# Reordering variables using the mean value of a separate column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset of the form

```
  regional.indicator ladder.score
1 A                   100
2 A                   200
3 B                   30
4 B                   40
5 C                   50
```

where I am trying to reorder the variables by the mean `ladder.score` in a factor named `regional.indicator` and assign this new vector to `order1`[(similar to this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471467/reordering-columns-in-an-r-dataframe-according-to-average-values/23471618). My issue is that the code replies with the error that the `regional.indicator` does not exist.

***Example***

```
library(dplyr)

# Create dataset
 df <- data.frame(regional.indicator = c("A","A","B","B","C"),
             ladder.score = c(100,200, 30,40,50))
             
# Change regional.indicator to factor
df$regional.indicator <- as.factor(df$regional.indicator)

# Function where the error arises
order1 <- df %>%  
           group_by(regional.indicator)%>%
           summarise(Laddermean = mean(ladder.score))%>%
           arrange(Laddermean)%>%
           pull(regional.indicator)
```

***Error message that arose:***

```
Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist.
x Column `regional.indicator` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I get rid of this error or do this in a different way? Perhaps using `forcats`?

Comment: The code looks like it should work but I get the same error when I try it on my computer.

Comment: I like the syntax of `df$order1 = forcats::fct_reorder(df$regional.indicator, df$ladder.score, mean)`

Comment: @JonSpring, would this work exactly the same way?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand your goal correctly. The line I suggested would create a new variable in your `df` called `order1` which is your `regional.indicator` as an ordered factor based on the mean of `ladder.score`.

Comment: @ JonSpring this would not work for my case as it prints all the values out, I need to have the order so that I can use it as a precise order vector, like c("A","C","B"). The reason is that I then manipulate this further.

Comment: @JonSpring I am trying to make a vector that orders the factors in <code>regional.indicator</code> by their mean <code>ladder.score</code>. This is to then to be used to extract values from another dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not solved your problem -> then do this:

Just add `dplyr::` to `summarise`. I guess dplyr's `summarise` interfer with `plyr` package on your system:

**replace:**

`summarise(Laddermean = mean(ladder.score))%>%`

**with**

`dplyr::summarise(Laddermean = mean(ladder.score))%>%`